# Macros to sum unique values related to another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to create macros to populate in "Metrics calculator" tab, the sum of "No of test steps"(Column G) for each "study" (Column D). The sum should consider unique values only. Please see the table below:
[image: Table]

In this Study no '1111', total step no/patient no '20' repeated 3 times, '15' repeated 4 times and '30'  3 times- i need the macros just to take unique values and add,i.e just 20+15+30=65.

In Metrics calculator tab"- It should come with output as

Study no    Total no of steps
1111    65

Comment: Is your "total step no?Patient no" 20 or 1, 2, 3 ? The third column is headed "total step no?Patient no" but you refer to numbers in the second column....

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1705-excel-sum-average-unique-values.html - Give implementing that a try and then come back with any issues you may have.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand the question, you want to sum the unique values in column B. The following will do the trick.

Note, you will need to adgust the range as necessary. Right now the range is set to B2:B20 as in your sample table.

```
Sub unique()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim arrElem As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim elem As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim stepSum As Long
    Dim match As Boolean

    Set Rng = Range("B2:B20") 'Edit this so that it fits your array

    'this sets up an array to store unique variables
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 1) As Variant
    arr(1) = 0

    'this loops through each number in the identified range
    For Each elem In Rng

      'this is a boolean, false means the current number is unique (so far) true means the number has been seen previously.
      match = False

      'this checks the current number against all the unique values stored in the array
      For Each arrElem In arr
          'If it finds a match, it changes the boolean to true
          If arrElem = elem Then match = True
      Next arrElem

      'If not match was found, we store the current number as a new unique value in the array
      If match = False Then
        'this adds another row to the array
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr) + 1) As Variant
        'this adds the unique value
        arr(UBound(arr)) = elem.Value
      End If

    Next elem

    'this sums the unique numbers we stored in the array
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        stepSum = stepSum + arr(i)
    Next i

    'this reports the sum of unique elements
    MsgBox stepSum

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Review this example :

[image]

In our sample ,cells(vendor names) in "column B" are listed as unique values  into "column K" :

```
Columns("B:B").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Columns( _
        "B:B"), CopyToRange:=Range("'Sheet1'!K1"), Unique:=True
```

Later , to sum these items(amounts in column I) in column "L" ,we entered SUMIF formula to cells in column L  using a loop  :

```
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
       Cells(i, "L").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C[-10],RC[-1],C[-3])"
Next i
```

Source : [Excel vba sum unique items](https://eksi30.com/sum-unique-values-in-excel-with-vba-codes/)